# Mistake in the proof of Theorem 2.24 of Quiver Representations by Ralf Schiffler?

Tags: representation-theory, proof-explanation, projective-module, quiver

I’m currently reading through Ralf Schiffler’s *Quiver Representations*, but I’m having trouble with the proof of the theorem below.
In the following, $Q$ denotes a finite, acyclic quiver with set of vertices $Q_0$, and for every $i \in Q_0$ we denote by $P(i)$ the corresponding indecomposable projective representation over the ground field $k$.

> **Theorem 2.24.**
>   Subrepresentations of projective representations in $\operatorname{rep} Q$ are again projective.
>
> *Proof.*
>   Suppose that $P$ is a projective representation with dimension vector $(d_i)_{i \in Q_0}$.
>   We will prove the theorem by induction on $d = \sum_{i \in Q_0} d_i$, the dimension of $P$.
>
> If $d = 1$, then $P$ is simple and there is nothing to prove.
>   So suppose that $d > 1$.
>   Let $M$ be a subrepresentation of $P$ and let $u \colon M \to P$ be the inclusion morphism.
>   By Corollary 2.21, we have $P \cong P(i_1) \oplus \dotsb \oplus P(i_t)$ for some vertices $i_1, \dotsc, i_t$, and thus the inclusion $u$ is of the form
>   $$
>     u
>   = \begin{bmatrix}
>       u_1     \\
>       \vdots  \\
>       u_t
>     \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   with $\operatorname{im} u_j \subseteq P(i_j)$.
>   **It follows that $M \cong \operatorname{im} u_1 \oplus \dotsb \oplus \operatorname{im} u_t$,** and by Propositition 2.7, it sufficies to show that $\operatorname{im} u_j$ is projective for each $j$.
>   This is obvious in the case where $\operatorname{im} u_j = P(i_j)$, so let us suppose that $\operatorname{im} u_j$ is a proper subrepresentation of $P(i_j)$.
>   Then $\operatorname{im} u_j$ is a subrepresentation of $\operatorname{rad} P(i_j)$, and $\operatorname{rad} P(i_j)$ is projective by Lemma 2.23.
>   Moreover, the dimension of $\operatorname{rad} P(i_j)$ is stricly smaller than $d$, and, by induction, we conclude that $\operatorname{im} u_j$ is projective, which completes the proof.

I don’t understand why $M \cong \operatorname{im} u_1 \oplus \dotsb \oplus \operatorname{im} u_t$, and suspect that this might be wrong:

Consider the quiver $Q$ consisting of a single vertex, labeled $1$, and no edges.
Then representations of $Q$ over $k$ are just $k$-vector spaces, and we have that $P(1) = k$.
Then $P := k^2 = P(1) \oplus P(1)$ is a projective representation of $Q$, and the diagonal $M = \{(x,x) \mid x \in k\}$ is a subrepresentation of $P$.
With respect to the decomposition $P = P(1) \oplus P(1)$ the inclusion $u \colon M \to P$ takes the form
$$
    u
  = \begin{bmatrix}
      u_1 \\
      u_2
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $u_i \colon M \to P(1) = k$ is the projection onto the $i$-th component.
But then
$$
          M
  \cong   k
  \ncong  k^2
  =       \operatorname{im} u_1 \oplus \operatorname{im} u_2.
$$

> **Question:**
>   (Why) do we have that $M \cong \operatorname{im} u_1 \oplus \dotsb \oplus \operatorname{im} u_t$?

Comment: I agree that there is something funky going on here, but I'm not confident enough to say that the proof is wrong because maybe I'm just missing a subtlety in Schiffler's presentation. For $M$ to be isomorphic to the sum of those images, those images would have to be disjoint in $P$, which they're not.

Comment: I've seen other authors prove this same result only by constructing a length-$1$ projective resolution of a representation, so it's hard to compare this proof to the presentation in other books.

Comment: I noticed the same thing. There seems to be an issue with the proof as presented.

Comment: Oh, BTW. Here is a "fix": Consider the composition M->P->P(i) for some i in the decomposition of P. If the morphism is surjective, then P(i) is a summand of M. If not, then we can replace P(i) with rad P(i). Continue inductively.